# Moving code from one TFS server to another

Tags: tfs

I have a local structure of directories and files. This codebase is a latest version of all of my code. I now need to upload that into TFS. How do I upload a bunch of folders and files at once?

Currently, I'm looking in the "Source Control Explorer". I see "Add Items to Folder". However, I can't figure out how to upload folders and files to the project I want to add it to.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First, make sure your local folder is [mapped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181384.aspx) to a TFS
   workspace.
2. In the `Add Items to Folder` dialog set the folders
   and files you want in the `Items to add` and `Exlcuded items` tabs. These items gets into the list of pending changes.
3. Check-in pending changes.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to keep your revision history you need to follow these steps:

http://www.robusthaven.com/blog/release-management/Migrating-TFS-to-New-Hardware

else follow @KMoraz answer to use source control explorer and right click to add items to the repository.